# Find programs listening to keyboard/mouse events

Tags: java, c++, windows, keyboard, mouseevent

Last few days my Windows 7 laptop is not responding to my mouse and keyboard clicks etc very smoothly. I wonder if there is some Trojan at work. May be I have too much time at hand, but I wonder if **there is a way to find all programs that are registered to listen to mouse/keyboard events?**

Symptoms:

- Some keyboard key-presses & mouse clicks are lost altogether (no response).
- Many a times a single click turns into a double click. Never happens with keyboard.
- Situation is the same with on-laptop trackpad + keyboard + mouse-buttons or external wired keyboard and mouse connected via USB via docking station.
- In general it's more noticeable with mouse than keyboard.

I don't mind the programming language, but I know C/C++/Java/Python the best.

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to find a virus programatically? If NOT then go to `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run` and check if there are any suspicious keys.. Most viruses tend to use these keys to run on startup.. Also check the `RunOnce` key while you're there.. Check the startup folder and appdata as well.. You can usually find most like this. Other than that, you're attempting to write your own virus scanner.. You can check incomming and outgoing connections using WireShark, WinPCap, etc..  ProcessMonitor will show any processes hidden from task manager..

Comment: I would think this would be very OS-Specific, if possible at all.

Comment: In the very least it would be OS-specific, and there's no way that this could be tied to Java. I recommend getting rid of the Java tag, and trying to make your question more specific, since it appears overly broad as written.

Comment: I believe it's specific enough: "find all programs that are registered to listen to mouse/keyboard events?" ON "Windows 7" AND "I don't mind the programming language".

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can get some idea from process monitor output. Procmon gives you running process and all process's access in the machine which includes file access/any registry access. You can get it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).